# PUT Object Request to S3 via custom proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, proxy, sdk

We have a service which servers as a proxy for uploading files to s3 in out Kubernetes service.
There is console SDK app written on Golang which can be installed under Windows or MacOS.
There is a Token service which used for retrieving temporary AWS credentials (accessKey, secretKey, sessionToken).

It works as follows.

By SDK, Use:

1. chooses a file,
2. clicks 'submit',
3. SDK app is getting temp AWS credentials from Token service,
4. the file is being sent to the proxy service (via AWS S3 SDK with temp creds configured)
5. the proxy service receives the request, does some logging, and proxies the request to S3.

Is it possible to send PUTObject request to the proxy service host name rather than to s3.amazonaws.com using Scala/Java AWS S3 SDK?

What I have tried:

```
  lazy val proxyConf: ProxyConfiguration = ProxyConfiguration.builder()
    .host("proxy-service-host")
    .port(80)
    .scheme("http")
    .build()

  lazy val httpClient: SdkAsyncHttpClient =
      NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder()
        .maxConcurrency(10)
        .proxyConfiguration(proxyConf)
        .build()

  lazy val credentials = AwsSessionCredentials.create("accessKey", "secretKey", "sessionToken")

  lazy val provider = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)

  lazy val config = S3Configuration.builder()
    .pathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
    .build();

  lazy val getAWSS3Client: S3AsyncClient = S3AsyncClient
    .builder()
    .serviceConfiguration(config)
    .credentialsProvider(provider)
    .httpClient(httpClient)
    .region(Region.of(sys.env.getOrElse("AWS_REGION", "us-west-2")))
    .build()
```

but getting:

```
Could not connect to proxy
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.ProxyTunnelInitHandler.channelRead(ProxyTunnelInitHandler.java:111)
```